# why error en Etherdelta?

Tags: contract-development, etherdelta

I made a transaction to upload my token in etherdelta but it gives me TxReceipt Status: Fail, does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x35d005938651e32ea04b69d9b0b2dc93e6a44265613dcb938cc54e699be8f58e

Answer (score 1):

That transaction appears to be trying to call a non-existent function called `approve`. This is a function that's part of the ERC20 token standard, but it doesn't look like it's implemented by the contract you're trying to call. (In short, it's not an ERC20 token, so you will probably not be able to use it with EtherDelta.)